# One line alternative to repeated function calls with setInterval in react components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 3 functions which are running repeatedly within my react component.
They're working fine but I'd like to clean up the code so that I can just call the function repeatedly without having to initialize and then set the interval.

Is there a way to call the function and set the interval without the initial function call in componentDidMount?

```
export class CryptoData extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
    pair: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }

    state = {
        price: null,
        change1Hr: null,
        change24Hr: null
    }

    getAsync = (func, state) => {
        func(this.props.pair).then(res => {
            this.setState({ [state]: res })
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getAsync(getPrice, "price")
        this.getAsync(get1HrChange, "change1Hr")
        this.getAsync(get24HrChange, "change24Hr") // <- Remove fist 3 lines?
        this.interval = setInterval(() => this.getAsync(getPrice, "price"), 15000)
        this.interval = setInterval(() => this.getAsync(get1HrChange, "change1Hr"), 30000);
        this.interval = setInterval(() => this.getAsync(get24HrChange, "change24Hr"), 20000)
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
```

Comment: Consider to use WebSockets instead of calling api every `n` milisecconds. It would be much cleaner solution in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I think you're right. I'm using Django as a backend and I've had problems implementing websockets in the past but it's definitely a hurdle I need to overcome now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With hooks you could abstract all the logic to get and update a value into one hook:

```
 function useUpdatedData(fetcher, interval) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
    
   useEffect(() => {
     let timer;
     async function update() {
        setValue(await fetcher());
        timer = setTimeout(update, interval); 
      }
      update();
      return () => clearTimeout(timer);
    }, [fetcher]);
  
    return value;
 }

 function CryptoData() {
    const price = useUpdatedData(getPrice, 1500);
    //...
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I haven't used hooks before but I can see that they're something I'll need to learn. Is it also preferred to create components in the functional form instead of `Component extends Component`?

Comment: I prefer it cause as shown here, with hooks you can abstract even more logic into reusable parts. I'm always a bit careful with general "it is preferred" statements, choose what works best for you.

Comment: Accepting this since hooks are the all round best answer here. Websockets are also a good alternative